# How to create new resource for Sitemap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

I'm trying to make a dynamic sitemap, which I can update with a rake task every time I want, since my site is a social network that changes constantly.

For that, I'm using a gem called sitemap_generator https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator, which seems easy to use.

In the sitemap.rb file, where you need to add your resources, it says:

```
# Add all articles:
  #
  #   Article.find_each do |article|
  #     add article_path(article), :lastmod => article.updated_at
  #   end
```

I'm using nested resources so my photos path is user_photo_path, and I'm trying to add every resource like this:

```
  Photo.find_each do |photo|
    add user_photo_path(photo[:user_id, :id]), :lastmod => photo.updated_at
  end
```

It's not working, it will give an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Any ideas how should I add this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
photo[:user_id, :id]
```

Do you mean:

```
photo[:user_id], photo[:id]
```

perhaps? If not, what is `user_photo_path` expecting?

Comment: It's quicker to type `photo.user_id` and `photo.id` by the way. ActiveRecord gives you some nice accessors.

Comment: Perfect answer, still don't understand how things are expected. Sometimes (:user_id,:id), sometimes (@user.photo.id,@photo.id)... :(

Comment: Easy to get confused, don't worry. You'll come to terms with it as you keep using and questioning it. The _url and _path helpers are generally quite forgiving though - you can pass in objects, ids, an array or a hash IIRC. When they make sense.